# Email Regular Expression

Tags: regex, email

I need a regular expression where I can allow it to end in .com AND mydomain.local.  I can have two separate regular expressions based on environments because the email domains are different.

Can someone help me out with the mydomain.local?  I think I have the one for .com working fine

So the email could be: email@test.mydomain.local or email@mydomain.local, but I need it to END in mydomain.local.

For some reason the .com doesn't work with mydomain.local.

.com regular expression built at runtime based on environment:

```
        sb.Append(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*?\.");
        sb.Append("[");
        sb.Append(emailDomainLower);
        sb.Append("|");
        sb.Append(emailDomainUpper);
        sb.Append("]");
        sb.Append("{");
        sb.Append(emailDomainLower.Length.ToString());
        sb.Append("}");

        string finalRegexPutTogether = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: The better way is to use [MailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to validate the email, then pick out the domain and use regex to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

This one comes out of the Hartl Rails tutorial, just tested it for your string pattern and it works:
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

Comment: Where do I specify mydomain.local though?  To make sure it ends in that?